# How can I add UIButtons to my TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, cell

I'm 14 and I live in Germany, sorry for my bad English!

I would like to add UIButtons to my TableViewCells that call their own index when they get tapped.

I use Swift 4.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First create outlet your UIButton to your tableviewCell class

Now in your viewController

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
       cell.bttnName.tag = indexPath.row // The indexPath Row will be stored an button's tag
        cell.bttnName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedButton), for: .touchUpInside)


        return cell
    }
```

Now create a target function for the button (Button action)

```
 @objc func selectedButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        let button = sender!
        print("Clicked Index:",button.tag)
}
```

Your clicked button cell index can be fetched by just calling `button.tag`

Comment: Does not work for me :(

Comment: @Thomas Please show your code